# error says input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to get the data under the sql column "Price" using its ItemName when I select from a dropdown and enter a quantity (which will then be inserted as an sql row selecteditemfromdropdown on ItemName column + Quantity on Qty column + the price I'm trying to get from another table).

I used a datasettable adapter "datPrice" and stored it on a data table "tblPrice". The error occured on the line

```
int price = Convert.ToInt32(tblPrice.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString());
```

becuase it says that

> Input string was not in a correct format

How can I solve the error?

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSetTableAdapters.RawMaterialMFTableAdapter datItemName = new DataSetTableAdapters.RawMaterialMFTableAdapter();
    DataTable tblItemID = new DataTable();
    tblItemID = datItemName.GetDataByItemName(drpItemName.Text);
    int itemID = Convert.ToInt32(tblItemID.Rows[0]["ItemID"].ToString());

    DataSetTableAdapters.RawMaterialMFTableAdapter datPrice = new DataSetTableAdapters.RawMaterialMFTableAdapter();
    DataTable tblPrice = new DataTable();
    tblPrice = datPrice.GetDataByPrice(drpItemName.Text);

    int price = Convert.ToInt32(tblPrice.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString());  // Error on this line
    int total = price * Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text.ToString());

    DataSetTableAdapters.QRawMaterialTableAdapter datData = new DataSetTableAdapters.QRawMaterialTableAdapter();
    datData.InsertQueryQRM(itemID, Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text.ToString()), price, total);
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code and check what value you are getting in `tblPrice.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString()` ?

Comment: Dollars/Prices are typically stored as Decimals, have you tried that? `var price = Convert.ToDecimal(tblPrice.Rows[1]["Price"].ToString());** `, also check the first row contains a number value for Price.

Comment: Do you mean the datatype i'm getting or a parameter i'm using? Sorry i'm not very good at this

Comment: @JeremyThompson i did and got an error that says "An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: Change the index to 0

Comment: Are there are rows in your tblPrice??? Sounds like it's empty. Do yourself a favor and pick up a beginner c# book

Comment: I made sure there are before I did this. Sadly I'm in a rush and does not have time for that :((

Comment: The best way of proceeding is to look at the data table.  Put a break point on the line the is giving the error by selecting the line and then pressing F9.  Run the code until it breaks.  Then hover over the variable tblPrice and press down arrow and select Data Table Visualizer.  Then check to make sure the price is a number that can be converted to a decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int price = int.Parse(tblPrice.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString());`

try it.

Comment: I did but whatever I do it seems that it's not getting the price from its table. Thank you anyway, I'm gonna try to do more experimenting then

Comment: did you try to remove .ToString? and by the way is your tblPrice is decimal?

Comment: I DID AND IT WORKED THANKS SO MUCH for helping and being patient with me!